# Angular page go to wrong route at it's first load?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

At my angular app after I reload the page I get the empty shell html page not my home page as my expectation even when the url point to the home route http://localhost:8444/home.

**Please point out what is wrong with my code ?

or what should i do to fix this behavior ?**

the app at server side contain one cshtml page with `ng-include` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
    <base href="/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
            app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', configurRoutes]);
            function configurRoutes($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $stateProvider
                    .state(
                    'home', {
                        url: '/home',
                        template: '<div>At Home Page</div>'
                    });
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-include="'/app/layout/shell.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**shell.html**

```
<div>
In the shell
<hr/>
<a ui-sref="home"> home </a> 
<div ui-view></div>
```

**here is the problem at first load I get the empty shell page, Notice that url pointing to home page**
[image]

**after click on go home it is working as expected**
[image]

**Update**
after I moved the content of the shell.html to the cshtml it worked as expected but without ng-include

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an otherwise('home') clause to your stateProvider